# How can I parse this form?

Tags: python, parsing

Input:

```
NAME: amiee AGE: 10 SHCOOL: elementary school
```

this is really long form, maybe there are more than 10 subjects.
How can I parse this sentence easily without `split`...?
I want to save this form to dictionary, like.

```
{amiee:{AGE:10, SCHOOL: elementary school ... }}
```

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Comment: Why do you want to parse it "without split"?

Comment: @blhsing: Likely because it's a school homework assignment or something similar.

Comment: @blhsing Because I solved this problem with...... manual split, like  : data.split("NAME:")[1], but I don't think this is the best way for scalable form

Comment: @blhsing and also using C language, we can solve this problem with simple line! scanf!  but I'm just curious if it has a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to extract a list of key-value pairs from the input string, use it to create an intermediate dict, then pop the name from the dict, and create a new dict with the name and what's left in the intermediate dict:

```
import re
form = 'NAME: amiee AGE: 10 SHCOOL: elementary school'
d = dict(re.findall(r'([A-Z]+): (.*?)(?=\s*[A-Z]+: |$)', form))
name = d.pop('NAME')
print({name: d})
```

This outputs:

```
{'amiee': {'AGE': '10', 'SHCOOL': 'elementary school'}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about |$ ,  thank you!